# Adding a predefined variable in select in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that lists all installed applications on all the servers I have on my network.

The problem is that I am unable to list server name. How do I add `$server.name` to the select statement so that it is the first column in the output?

```
 # Pinging the server in Powershell-way!
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server.name -count 1 -Quiet ) {
    echo -computername 
    echo $server.name
    echo $services = $services, 
        (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server.name win32_product | select name, vendor, version | Export-CSV -Path $File -Force -Append -Verbose)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should replace:

```
(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server.name win32_product | select name, vendor, version | Export-CSV -Path $File -Force -Append -Verbose)
```

With:

```
(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server.name win32_product | select pscomputername, name, vendor, version | Export-CSV -Path $File -Force -Append -Verbose)
```

/edit, yes PScomputer name is what you are after, in futureuse get-member have a look at your options

Answer (score 0):

I was too quick to ask the question.
There is a variable called **PSComputerName** in win32_product which is the meachine name